# Conditional type doesn't recognize that all inputs result in same conditional result

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

This example doesn't typecheck:

```js
type Subset1 = "one" | "two";
type Subset2 = "three" | "four";
type All = Subset1 | Subset2;

type Other = {
    "one": number,
    "two": string,
    "three": boolean,
    "four": object,
};

type Extra<V> = V extends Subset1 ? string : undefined;

function doOtherThing(stuff: string){}

function doThing<V extends All>(value: V, params: Other[V], extra: Extra<V>) { }

function doSubset1Thing<V extends Subset1>(value: V, params: Other[V], extra: string) {
    doThing(value, params, extra);

    doOtherThing(extra);
}

function doSubset2Thing<V extends Subset2>(value: V, params: Other[V]) {
    doThing(value, params, undefined);
}
```

([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwM4WARigXigIgPYB2EOUAPrsAO544DcAUKJLIisAExYUAWAThMTK4AZnji86jcNACCAGzld4yVBnLK27BlOYB5YNwi8uAb3pQLuQsQBcUAnAC2CIwBpzlnFRp2kwXgCWBADm7pY8-LZQCHh4chAAhgRhnqLiOHZ4CABWEADGwO4AvtpM0ACiAB7+CQA8AGoAfFz1UBDVEAQAJkgsKuhQAPxQfoEhUHZw3RDCQRBd2sJTBQGEUF14+oa8ACrcQcEAFH5wwsK+-gcAlCZF9PRLBCtrG3sHDW0d3b3yco2HADcEnI4BA7PVXFAwAleAlHEg7FsjABteoAXUh7RqdiqNQajSuUBMUDuD2WwFWBHWeA0qjeIQ+WM6PT6bDQ-yBILBUAhUJhcIRUCRvFRGM+2JGlxChLM4Ve+xCgOBoMh0Nh8Mx1VhV20cs2BiM9KOWO1DFJj2eVI2tI4RsZXxZNvYHOV3N5aoFiINIvRMo8FnlByVXNV-I1UCmXRmcy6OvoRSAA))

The error is because `extra` is hardcoded `string` in `doSubset1Thing`, but logically it *is* always a string because `value` is limited to `Subset1`, and `Extra<Subset1>` properly resolves to `string`, but for some reason, the call to `doThing` does not recognize that.

Similarly, inverting it for `doSubset2Thing` errors even though the third param will always be `undefined`.

For the second one, I can sort of see issues if `Subset1` and `Subset2` overlapped, but they don't, so I'd have assumed that TS would flatted that all out to `undefined` for `doSubset2Thing`.

Is there any way to make this work? Alternatively, am I missing something that actually does make this invalid?

Comment: Well I'm stumped. Really want to know the answer to this...

Comment: At least it's not just me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is an instance where your code is logically correct and type-safe, but Typescript just isn't able to prove it because it lacks a rule that would be able to prove it. A simple rule like *"`V` must extend `Subset1` because that's its upper bound"* would be good enough, but apparently Typescript isn't (currently) programmed to use such a rule.

One fix, which may make more sense for your use-case than a conditional type anyway, is to use function overloads: this also saves you from having to pass an explicit `undefined` in the second case.

```
function doThing<V extends Subset1>(value: V, params: Other[V], extra: string): void;
function doThing<V extends Subset2>(value: V, params: Other[V]): void;
function doThing<V extends All>(value: V, params: Other[V], extra?: string): void {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwM4WARigXigIgPYB2EOUAPrsAO544DcAUKJLIisAExYUAWAThMTK4AZnji86jcNACCAGzld4yVBnLK27BlOYB5YNwi8uAb3pQLuQsQBcUAnAC2CIwBpzlnFRp2kwXgCWBADm7pY8-LZQCHh4chAAhgRhnqLiOHZ4CABWEADGwO4AvtrCcAQFAYRQACZ4ACrcQcEAPABqUBAAHsAQBDVILCroAHwAFABuCXJwEHZtrlBgCbwJjkh2+oa8ANptALqL3f4Jvv7NAJR2E3gBNQxlFcBVBLUNTSHtnT19A0Oa4ymMzmUAWSxWaw2UC2Rj2+yuUBudwe5Uq1TqjWaX2Ov0G8jkgOms3mi2Wq3WmwMsIORx6qwA-GdAiEEUialAzOEAPRcqAAOgF9CK9HojzRrzqGlUmM+HRx-UGUtGkyJILBZMhlO2cNpJyZlw5HgsGI+wRVwNJEPWutWFwYwtFqOe6LwSvYMtacp+Cv+qHYhOBJPB5KhMN2BwuhvCJua5tmlpDdqF9CAA)

Comment: Awesome, looks like that works, I hadn't thought about overloads as an alternative at all.